# How xml serialze german umlaut character in .Net that works on all pcs?

Tags: .net, xml, encoding, xmlwriter

I am trying to serialize text to xml file that contains of german ä character, when I run this code on one PC it works fine, on other PC instead of ä I am getting д or &#x434, on other PC when I run code I am getting square. I tried different things, here is my code:

```
string text = "säure";


XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlnsEmpty = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

xmlnsEmpty.Add("", ""); // This line solves the issue with saving XML file with German letters on some PCs
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
var utfWithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
      Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, // Use UTF-8 to support German letters
    Indent = true,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,

};

using var stream = new FileStream("output.xml", FileMode.Create);
//using var sw = new StreamWriter(stream,Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, text, xmlnsEmpty);
```

For example I am getting this result:

[image]

As you can see from my code I tried almost everything, but notihng helps. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using ISO-8859-1? Just use UTF-8 everywhere. It's not clear what you mean by "I am getting" either - how are you viewing the file afterwards?

Comment: I tried also with UTF-8, and afterwards I open file in Notepad++ and Visual studio, tha same

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] then so we can try this for ourselves. But a *lot* of what you're doing is entirely unnecessary. It should all just work fine - my guess is that when you're *viewing* the file, Notepad++ or VS is just not guessing correctly that it's UTF-8.

Comment: I'm getting I mean that when I view xml file, in that file in my xml text instead of ä there is another symbols. but for example if I generate xml on PC that works fine, and then open that file on other PC that doesn't work I see the correct symbol

Comment: Well how are you sending the file from one PC to another? That could be where the problem is. I suggest you create an absolutely minimal example, and then look at the *precise bytes* of the file in working and broken cases, using a binary file editor or something similar.

Comment: No, when I am sending file it is opening ok. But when I generate file and open it in the same PC, it doesn't work for some PCs

Comment: I'll be very glad to provide you minimal reproductive example, but it is very hard, because the real code is confidential. let me think what can I do

Comment: That doesn't make it hard. You create a class with a single string property, and serialize that. Hard-code the value in your [mcve] to "xäx" before you serialize - very simple.

Comment: I change my code in the example please can you look at?

Comment: I know that it is very hard to reproduce, because if it works on your pc you can not do anything. I hat one PC in which it works fine, and 2 PCs on which it doesn't work

Comment: You can at least show a *complete* example that fails on the PC where it doesn't work... and give details about what *exactly* is in the file afterwards. (For example, you could read it with `File.ReadAllBytes` and then use `BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` to show the bytes.)

Comment: (The edited code is still using ISO-8859-1. Don't do that. Just using the default settings should be fine. And I very much doubt that the `XmlSerializerNamespaces` is relevant *at all*.)

Comment: the code that I put here is the full example, I just create .net console app, run it and get this results

Comment: But it's still using ISO-8859-1 - and it's far from minimal. And it doesn't tell us what *bytes* are in the file afterwards. I'm afraid I don't have time to keep coming back again and again. Hopefully after you've put some more work into the question, someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: `Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),` take this line out, and use the commented line above.

Comment: when I take this out it works on sample example, but doesn't work in real code. In real code I try with UTF8 but doesnt help. I guess it is related to model xsd scheme, but can not figure out how

Comment: Focus on what the actual bytes/octets in the file are, not on how they appear when viewed on screen. You need to separate the two problems: getting the right bytes in the file, and getting them displayed properly when viewed using a variety of display software.